# Knockout.js : Binding to a function on the click-event using the Repository-Pattern

Tags: javascript, binding, knockout.js, repository-pattern

I got stuck trying to implement the Repository-Pattern in Knockout.js.
I find it difficult to handle the click event because:

**Problems**:

1. on click: pendDeleteItem is not called. I can not find the scope ;(
2. in PendDeleteItem i have a this-Problem. i need to get to the PendingItem property.

**working fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/ThomasDeutsch/j7Qxh/8/

**Goal**:

On click the Item gets send to PendingItem.

Restrictions: i want to keep the ko.applyBindings(ViewModel) if possible, because i want to add more Repositoris and define the data-bind in the html like: customer.pendDeleteItem

Answer (score 2):

The first part of your problem is simple. Look at the markup for your button:

```
<button data-bind"click: $root.customer.pendDeleteItem "> sendTo -> PendingItems</button>
```

You are missing the `=` after the `data-bind` attribute name. Change it to this:

```
<button data-bind="click: $root.customer.pendDeleteItem "> sendTo -> PendingItems</button>
```

The next problem is that `this` in the click handler refers to the "item", not to the view model. You will need to change these lines:

```
this.PendingItems.push(item);
this.Items.remove(item);
```

To refer to your view model:

```
ViewModel.customer.PendingItems.push(item);
ViewModel.customer.Items.remove(item);
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7Qxh/9/).

Comment: I want do add several Repositorys in my ViewModel - so it is not possible to refference the Object by its name in the ViewModel. Is there a solution? And thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

For the Second Problem:
This Binding will solve it:

```
data-bind="click: function() { $root.customer.pendDeleteItem($data)}
```

This is the corresponding js where i can refference this with "this" :)

```
pendDeleteItem = function(item) {
        console.log("pendDeleteItem called");
        item.Operation = 'DELETE';
        this.PendingItems.push(item);
        this.Items.remove(item);
    };
```